# SSRS Subreports Performance

Tags: reporting-services

I have a main report with three sub reports (ReportA,ReportB,ReportC).

Have one parameter with values A,B,C

written a expression in visible property of all the sub reports.

when the user selects param A,only Report A will be displayed.
will all the sub reports process at the same time?

when we process the report individually its taking seconds but if i run from the main report its taking nearly 2 mins.

how can we disable the processing of the Report B,C when the user selects report A.

Comment: Probably this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277714/sql-server-reporting-services-how-to-stop-a-report-firing-when-opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include an `AND :ParameterName = 'Y'` condition in the where clause of each reports dataset query - if your parameter is not`'Y'`, the query will still fire, but it will immediately return 0 records. And the time taken by the non visible reports will be minimized. Or you can set the expression for the query execution on the `Dataset`