# SSRS report with multi valued parameter rendering slow first time

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have SSRS(VS 2008) report with multi valued parameter rendering slow for the first time. Hope when the report renders for the first time, it shouldn't even look at the big/main SQL query. I have datasets(with SQL query) for each parameter. There are 12 parameters on the report.

Any thoughts about how to improve the performance atleast when reports renders for the first time.

Comment: Does this problem occur when you run the report from the Report server, but not in preview in Visual Studio? Does it only happen the first time you run the report in a day, but not the successive times during that day? Because that would be related to a known issue not caused by your report. Otherwise - take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277714/sql-server-reporting-services-how-to-stop-a-report-firing-when-opened

Comment: That happens most of the times, on report server and everywhere else but not when i preview in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like you'll want to fiddle with the parameters and their default values, as described in the post I linked, to stop the main query from running until the parameters are submitted. If that doesn't help, you could look into caching datasets: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636149.aspx

Comment: I don't think main query runs until i key in parameters and hit view report. See my problem is report rendering slow most of the time, having said that when it renders first time, the report would only show parameters no data or nothing.. that's why i think main is not executed until i choose parameters and hit View report button. Hope this part is clear now. So why does report takes long time to render which is only showing parameters and nothing else.. how can i fix that..

Comment: Perhaps you can test to see if the slowness is caused by the parameter queries running and populating the available values for the report. Try making a copy of the report and changing all the parameter available values and default values to "none". If it runs quickly, the issue is likely with the queries used to populate the parameter values. Depending on the parameters and your requirements, you may be able to specify that they never refresh, convert some to lists of available values, or optimize the queries that they rely on.